How to call external localhost API from angular production server?
I'm trying to connect to an external printer on http://localhost:8080/api/connectPrinter.
The problem is when I'm trying to call it from a production env (SIT,STG,etc.)
If I just call the API like : http.post(http://localhost:8080/api/connectPrinter) (or 127.0.0.1) I get a CORS error. I've tried proxy.conf using a pathRewrite, but it only works in local env. I've search online but I haven't seem to find the right solution. I'm using angular 15,
Is there anyway to solve this? Do I need to configure it from the server (i.e. printer)? Please point me in the right direction.

CORS errors are handled on the server only, so this is unlikely to be an angular question. You should remove the angular tag and use the tag of your server technology.
